# Is this correct usage of the word 天资?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I have tried to find example sentences using 天资 tian zi (talent) online with no luck. I f I were to write 'he is a very talented pianist' or something of the sort, would it be correct to say

弹钢琴他有很多天资

?

Comment: no luck? jukuu has 83 sample sentences for 天资，readers of C much more familiar with 天赋 for which jukuu has the max number of 100 samples

Comment: Line Dictionary has 95 examples for 天资

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For talent in a specific area, the word [天份](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/6391/) is better choice than 天资, which can also means 'talent' but in a more general sense. When you say someone has 天份(talent), you need to specify in what subject the talent applies; When you say someone has 天资, it means that person has a nature ability to learn, doesn't matter what is the subject.

We don't measure 天份' with '多 and 少',  We measure '天资 or 天份' with '有 and 沒有' ; '高 and 低'

- 有天份; 沒有天份 (have talent/ talented; have no talent)
- 天份高: 天份低 (highly talented; low in talent/ not very talented)

> 弹钢琴他有很多天资 should be written as "**弹钢琴他很有天份**" which is a [topic]+[comment] sentence structure with "弹钢琴" as the topic and " 他很有天份" as the comment.

For a more common [S+V+O] structure, the sentence should be written as " **他很有弹钢琴的天份**"

> *Is this correct usage of the word 天资?*

Example of correct usage of the word 天资:

"他**天资**过人，學一年就能弹钢琴" - His **talent** is extraordinary, can play piano after only a year of learning.

"凭他的**天资**，考上多伦多大学不成问题" - With his **talent**, be admitted to the University of Toronto is not a problem.

Comment: "凭他的天资，..."  should be "凭他的天赋“。天资 is a status (smart) and not countable. so "他的天资过人” (he is very smart), but we cannot say “凭借他的天资"，we should say ”凭借他的天赋"。

Comment: 天赋  means 'natural gift" --  a smooth tongue , a strong arm, a tall body and of course, a smart brain are all 天赋(natural gift). While, 天资(natural ability) refers to a person's overall intelligence and ability.